# C++ Minimal CSV parser

Tags: c++, csv

I wrote a minimal CSV parser for my machine learning toy project.

```
class CSV {
public:
    using data_type = std::variant<int32_t, float, std::string>;
    using row_type = std::vector<data_type>;

private:
    std::vector<row_type> rows;
    std::vector<row_type> columns;
    std::vector<std::string> column_names;
    std::vector<int> column_data_types;
public:
    CSV(std::istream& is) {
        ParseCSV(is);
    }

    int32_t to_int(const std::string& str) {
        int32_t result = 0;
        auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
        return result;
    }

    float to_float(const std::string& str) {
        float result = 0;
        auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
        return result;
    }

    data_type to_data(const std::string& str, std::size_t col_index) {
        switch (column_data_types[col_index]) {
            case 0:
                return to_int(str);
                break;
            case 1:
                return to_float(str);
                break;
            case 2:
                return str;
                break;
            default:
                float result = 0.0f;
                auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
                if (ec == std::errc::invalid_argument) { // this data type is a string
                    column_data_types[col_index] = 2;
                    return str;
                } else if (result == std::floor(result)) { // this may be an integer
                    column_data_types[col_index] = 0;
                    return to_int(str);
                } else {
                    column_data_types[col_index] = 1;
                    return result;
                }
                break;
        }
        assert(0);
        return {};
    }

    void ParseHeader(std::istream& is, std::streamsize& len) {
        constexpr std::streamsize buf_len = 1024;
        std::array<char, buf_len> buffer = {0};
        std::string cell;
        while (len > 0) {
            std::streamsize read_len = std::min(len, buf_len);
            is.getline(&buffer[0], read_len);
            for (int i = 0; i < read_len; ++i) {
                if (buffer[i] == ',') {
                    column_names.push_back(std::move(cell));
                    cell = "";
                } else if (buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\0') {
                    column_names.push_back(std::move(cell));
                    cell = "";
                    len -= i;
                    column_data_types.resize(column_names.size(), -1);
                    return;
                } else {
                    cell += buffer[i];
                }
            }
            len -= read_len;
        }
        column_data_types.resize(column_names.size(), -1);
    }

    void ParseCSV(std::istream& is) {
        is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::streamsize len = is.tellg();
        is.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        ParseHeader(is, len);

        constexpr std::streamsize buf_len = 1024;
        std::array<char, buf_len> buffer = {0};
        std::string cell;
        row_type row;
        std::size_t col_index = 0;
        while (len > 0) {
            std::streamsize read_len = std::min(len, buf_len);
            is.read(&buffer[0], read_len);
            for (int i = 0; i < read_len; ++i) {
                if (buffer[i] == ',') {
                    row.push_back(to_data(cell, col_index));
                    cell = "";
                    col_index++;
                } else if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
                    row.push_back(to_data(cell, col_index));
                    cell = "";
                    col_index = 0;
                    rows.push_back(std::move(row));
                    row = {};
                } else {
                    cell += buffer[i];
                }
            }
            len -= read_len;
        }
        auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1);
        std::cout << rows.size() << " element read in " << dt.count() << " us\n";
    }
};
```

Reading 20628 lines from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/datasets/housing/housing.tgz gives, in my machine:

```
20628 element read in 89734 us
```

Feel free to comment anything!

Comment: I'm wondering why you have a 2-D array for `rows` _and_ for `columns`.  Does it hold the same data twice?

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5):

Your primitive conversion functions don't report errors.  Since your data type is a variant anyway, you could include an error type among them and return an error.

Use of `from_chars` is good!  These are new, efficient functions.

`to_data` uses hard-coded numbers in the switch statement and elsewhere.  It would be better to use an enumeration type.

You don't need to `break` after `return`.  The `return` itself is enough!

Why are you using fixed-size buffers for reading the lines?

`cell = "";` use `{}` for an empty string.  Converting `""` is inefficient because it uses the general string literal constructor!  But in this case, just use `cell.clear();`.

The code in `ParseHeader` is pretty slow and laborious.  You're reading one character at a time, using a loop over `i` the index for that matter (use a range-based `for` loop to do it directly), and pushing the character onto a string until you see the comma.  I scan for the comma or separators using standard algorithms and then grab the whole token at once.

I see `ParseCSV` is doing the same thing.  You don't need to copy the chars into another string, one-at-a-time or otherwise!  Find the delimiter, and then you have two pointers to the start and end of the token.  That's what `from_chars` wants!

It looks like you determine the cell type when reading the first row.  That might give false results, if the first value is "1" but it actually supports floating point so the next row has "2.4".  Or, it's not an integer but actually a string, as the second row has "B".

Here's my code that splits a string up at the commas.  It needs to know the number of fields at compile-time and thus avoids any dynamic memory allocation, but look at the body of the `for` loop for the actual logic; you can adapt that to whatever collections you are using.

```
template <size_t N>
auto split (char separator, std::string_view input)
{
    std::array<std::string_view, N> results; 
    auto current = input.begin();
    const auto End = input.end();
    for (auto& part : results)
    {
        if (current == End) {
            const bool is_last_part = &part == &(results.back());
            if (!is_last_part)  throw std::invalid_argument ("not enough parts to split");
        }
        //   core logic is here
        auto delim = std::find (current, End, separator);
        part = { &*current, size_t(delim-current) };
        current = delim;
        //  
        if (delim != End) ++current;
    }
    if (current != End)  throw std::invalid_argument ("too many parts to split");
    return results;
}
```

### architecture

You code has:

1. reading from a file
2. separating at delimiters
3. converting the tokens to the desired type
4. storing those converted tokens

all mixed together in one piece of code.  You may notice from my sample that it *only* does point 2.  Where that line of text came from is irrelevant, and subsequent points are not its responsibility.

Input doesn't have to come from a file or even a `istream` object:  it can scan a memory-mapped file that's already visible in RAM, or lines already in an array that came across via some message protocol, or literal constants, or anything.  The code does not need to be configured for this because it simply does not matter to what this code does, so none of that is part of it.  It takes a `string_view` to process one line.

I don't store the results in a two-dimensional array of variants, either.  I assign a row directly to a normal C++ structure that has named members with full type information.  Handling the conversion of strings to the proper types is another, general purpose, piece of code that's unrelated to the task of separating CSV fields.  Adding a user-defined type or other previously unused type does not require changing *this* code, because conversions is not part of it.

**Separations of Concerns** is good.  Even if you don't need flexibility, it makes each task simple and testable in isolation.

Comment: Can you benchmark your solution? I tried something similar after reading in a whole line, but it was less efficient than OP's solution.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes it's _fast_.  That's because the separator is a single char, not a string or choice of characters, and because it doesn't allocate any memory on the heap nor copies the strings it finds.  I didn't count the time needed to read a line from the file; that is a separate concern and this can be called with a whole file that's been slurped in and "separated" at newline, or an array of strings given to my code already in that form.

Comment: @JDługosz Thanks for your feedback, but when I've tried your solution (using ```std::string_view```), it turned out to be slower than the original solution for the reason I don't know. I'll post my two implementations and benchmark result

Comment: @G.Sliepen (and JDlugosz) Wait, I've benchmarked wrongly. The std::string_view approach definitely improved performance hugely. Posted the result

Answer (score 2):

It's surprisingly efficient. If I were to implement it myself, I would have gone with a `while(std::getline(...))` loop, so I always know I am dealing with a whole line at a time, and can pass a `std::string_view` into the line buffer instead of making a copy of each item into `cell`. But this was more than twice as slow as your solution, even if I reduce `buf_len` to just 16. There are a few improvements that could be made that I'll list below, but nothing really impacted performance.

## Use an `enum class` for the possible types

Instead of using raw integers to represent the type, create an `enum class` for it:

```
enum class type {
    UNKNOWN,
    INT,
    FLOAT,
    STRING,
};

std::vector<type> column_data_types;
```

This avoids magic constants and having to remember the index into `data_type` for a given type.

## Remove unused variables

The member variable `columns` is unused, as well as the local variables `ptr` and `ec` in `to_int()` and `to_float()`. Just remove them.

## Passing string iterators

Instead of calling `std::from_chars()` with `str.data()` and `str.data() + str.size()` as the parameters, just pass `str.begin()` and `str.end()`.

## Avoid unnecessary copies

Inside `ParseCSV()` you build a row in the temporary variable `row`, and then `std::move()` that into `rows`. While this is rather efficient since `std::vector` has a move constructor, you can avoid this altogether by adding an empty row to `rows` first, and then add cells to that row:

```
row.emplace_back(); // Ensure there is an empty row
...
while (len > 0) {
    ...
    if (buffer[i] == ',') {
        rows.back().emplace_back(to_data(cell, col_index));
        ...
    } else if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
        rows.back().emplace_back(to_data(cell, col_index));
        rows.emplace_back(); // This row is done, add a new one
        ...
    } else ...
```

## Consider making it more generic

It would be possible to reduce the amount of code you have to write somewhat by making more use of the type system. Instead of `column_data_types` being just a vector of *indices* into `data_type`, just make it a vector of `data_type` itself:

```
std::vector<data_type> column_data_types;
```

Then, instead of having `to_data()` having a `switch`-statement to call the right `to_something()` function, create a template `to<T>()` with overloads for the types you want to support, and `to_data()` use [`std::visit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) to call the right overload:

```
template<typename T>
T to(const std::string &str) = delete;

template<>
int to<int>(const std::string &str) {
    int32_t result = 0;
    std::from_chars(str.begin(), str.end(), result);
    return result;
}

...

data_type to_data(const std::string &str, std::size_t col_index) {
    if (std::holds_alternative(column_data_types[col_index])) {
        return std::visit([&](auto& type) {
             return to<decltype(type)>(str);
        }, column_data_types[col_index]);
    }

    // Else check the string to determine what type it is
    ...
    if (/* it's an int */) {
        column_data_types[col_index] = int{};
        return to<int>(str);
    }
    ...       
}
```

If you just support three types it's not worth it, but it might pay off when you want to support more types.