# C++ Minimal CSV parser cut2

Tags: c++, c++17, variant-type

Looking at this [questoin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/268428/c-minimal-csv-parser), I was inspired by the idea and the approach, so I tried to write a second version of the code, taking most of the comments into considerations.

Please note that I am still new to meta-programming, and I had a bit of challenge to make it work.

I notice that my version is slower than the original code, not sure where is the overhead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <charconv>
#include <fstream>
class CSV
{
public:
    using data_type = std::variant<int32_t, float, std::string>;
    using row_type = std::vector<data_type>;
    CSV(std::istream &is)
    {
        ParseCSV(is);
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    data_type convert(const std::string &str)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
        {
            return str;
        }
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float> or std::is_same_v<T, int32_t>)
        {
            T result = 0;
            std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
            return result;
        }
        throw std::logic_error("Conversion not supported\n");
    }
    data_type to_data(const std::string &str, std::size_t col_index)
    {
        if (col_index < column_data_types.size())
        {
            return std::visit([&](auto &t)
                              { return convert<std::decay_t<decltype(t)>>(str); },
                              column_data_types[col_index]);
        }
        float result = 0.0f;
        auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);
        if (ec == std::errc::invalid_argument)
        {
            column_data_types.push_back(std::string{});
        }
        else
        {
            column_data_types.push_back(result == std::floor(result) ? int32_t{} : float{});
        }
        return std::visit([&](auto &t)
                          { return convert<std::decay_t<decltype(t)>>(str); },
                          column_data_types.back());
    }

    void ParseHeader(std::istream &is, std::streamsize &len)
    {
        constexpr std::streamsize buf_len = 1024;
        std::array<char, buf_len> buffer = {0};
        std::string cell;
        while (len > 0)
        {
            std::streamsize read_len = std::min(len, buf_len);
            is.getline(&buffer[0], read_len);
            for (u_int i = 0; i < read_len; ++i)
            {
                if (buffer[i] == ',')
                {
                    column_names.push_back(std::move(cell));
                    cell = "";
                }
                else if (buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\0')
                {
                    column_names.push_back(std::move(cell));
                    len -= i;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell += buffer[i];
                }
            }
            len -= read_len;
        }
    }

    void ParseCSV(std::istream &is)
    {
        is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::streamsize len = is.tellg();
        is.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        ParseHeader(is, len);

        constexpr std::streamsize buf_len = 1024;
        std::array<char, buf_len> buffer = {0};
        std::string cell;
        std::size_t col_index = 0;
        rows.emplace_back();
        while (len > 0)
        {
            std::streamsize read_len = std::min(len, buf_len);
            is.read(&buffer[0], read_len);
            for (u_int i = 0; i < read_len; ++i)
            {
                auto &r = rows.back();
                if (buffer[i] == ',')
                {
                    r.emplace_back(to_data(cell, col_index));
                    cell = "";
                    col_index++;
                }
                else if (buffer[i] == '\n')
                {
                    r.emplace_back(to_data(cell, col_index));
                    cell = "";
                    col_index = 0;
                    rows.emplace_back();
                }
                else
                {
                    cell += buffer[i];
                }
            }
            len -= read_len;
        }
        auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto dt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1);
        std::cout << rows.size() << " element read in " << dt.count() << " us\n";
    }
    std::vector<row_type> rows;
    std::vector<std::string> column_names;
    std::vector<data_type> column_data_types;
};
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("/tmp/housing.csv");
    CSV c(file);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- The `CSV` class doesn't have any members to access or manipulate member data, apart from those used when constructing the class. So it probably shouldn't be a class at all. We can use a more functional style of programming to more closely match our needs; return a simple data struct from a "free" function:

```
    struct CSVData
    {
        using data_type = std::variant<int32_t, float, std::string>;
        using row_type = std::vector<data_type>;
        
        std::vector<row_type> rows;
        std::vector<std::string> column_names;
        std::vector<data_type> column_data_types;
    };
    
    CSVData parseCSV(std::istream& is);
```

- A "column name" row might exist for your particular use case, but it's not inherent to the CSV format. It might be better to parse it as any other row. The code for this program can access `rows[0]` as a column header if it wishes (after checking that it exists). If you then want to reuse the CSV parser in another program (or just for different data), you won't have to change the parser or add a new version without the column names.
- (The current duplication in parsing code for the header and the rows would also be avoided).
- Although you check for a null character when parsing the header, you don't do that while parsing ordinary rows. Note that null characters in your buffer may have been previously overwritten, and that your file may not end with a null character or a newline. So the last line of input may not actually be stored.
- Note that we don't *have* to read into an intermediate buffer. The file stream already does buffering of its own. If we wanted to, we could [imbue the stream with a locale that defines whitespace as we desire](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char), and use the stream to do the text processing. This is (as with most C++ iostreams code) admittedly kinda horrific. So a fixed length buffer is probably fine, or we could just read char by char (since file streams are already buffered).
- We could, however, use existing algorithms to process our buffer. `std::find_first_of` is one possibility. `std::strpbrk` or `std::strcspn` (used with great caution) are others.
- Auto-detecting types is a bad idea (c.f. Microsoft Excel and date formatting). There's no requirement in a CSV file that a column should contain only one type. Even if something looks like a number, we may want to use it as a string.

  The conversion can be delayed until the program (that knows about the specific file format) needs to do so. We might supply a conversion function to do this for a given cell, e.g.:

```
    template<class T>
    T get_as(std::size_t col, std::size_t row) const;
```

- This all suggests a different approach to parsing:

  1. Read the whole file into memory (into a std::string, or std::vector).
  2. Parse the file, and store the offset and size (or pointer and size, perhaps as a std::span or std::string_view) for each cell.
  3. The user accesses cells and asks for specific types as required.

  Note that this is fine for a generic, re-usable CSV reader for small files. But if what we actually need is to parse a specific set of data from (what happens to be) a CSV file, we should write C++ data structures to describe our data, and *then* write specific parsing code for that file type. (Such parsing code might use the generic CSV reader, or... it might not. When we know exactly what types we expect from the file, we can probably generate much more efficient parsing code and throw or return with an error when we hit something unexpected.)
- For large files, we probably don't want to store the whole thing in memory. In that case, we'd need to use the latter approach - parsing the expected data format field by field. Perhaps a couple of input-iterators (say a `csv_row_iterator` and a `csv_field_iterator`) would be reusable and fun to implement.

  (I'm sure there are plenty of other CSV reader implementations out there to get ideas from).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `user673679's` excellent review I have a couple of points to make.

## Use Standard Types

I have tried compiling this in both Visual Studio 2022 C++ and the current version of g++. Neither compiler accepts u_int as a type. There are uintXXX types that are standard, but I would suggest using `std::size_t` since that is what really would be proper. `std::size_t` is generally used for the size of objects and for indexing into arrays. [std::size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).

Current code:

```
            std::streamsize read_len = std::min(len, buf_len);
            is.read(&buffer[0], read_len);
            for (u_int i = 0; i < read_len; ++i)
            { ... }
```

Suggested code:

```
            std::size_t read_len = std::min(len, buf_len);
            is.getline(&buffer[0], read_len);
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < read_len; ++i)
            {
```

## Avoid Comparisons Between Different Types

Warning, `std::streamsize` is signed so if you are using the correct flags when compiling the `for` loop reports a warning on the comparison of `i` and `read_len`. I would actually use `std::size_t` for both `i` and `read_len`.

## Possible Optimizations

Use iterators in the `for` loops rather than indexing through the buffer. An optimizing compiler might generate the same code but it isn't guaranteed and iterators are generally faster than indexing.